# why does statement below loop executes before termination of loop

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why do i get alert before printing all vlaues

```
<script>
    for(var i=0; i<=1000; i++)
    {
        console.log(i);
    }
    alert('Hello');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is not executing before loop, it is executing correctly.

Your console may be refreshing little late.

Answer (score 1):

`alert()` will [*block* your browser whilst waiting to be dismissed by the user](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ewVsR/).

Maybe they haven't been written to the `console` yet by the time the alert appears. It depends on what your `console` object is.

BTW, they appear fine in the console before the alert in my Chrome 10 on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

The console is lagging behind. The loop *is* executed first. This shows it better:

```
var t = [];
for(var i=0; i<=1000; i++)
{
    t.push(i);
}
console.log(t.length);
alert('Hello');
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you executing this? My console doesn't show the alert until all the numbers are displayed. Yours must be lazily rendering output. So the loop does finish before the alert, but the log was only written to a buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
INSTRUCTION A;
INSTRUCTION B;
INSTRUCTION C;
</script>
```

In javascript the execution of INSTRUCTION B is not dependent upon completion of A and similarly for C.

You may want to try something like:

```
var test = 0;
var i=0;
while(test!=1) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
  if(i==1000) {
    alert("Hi!");
    test=1;
  }
}
```

Comment: That is how it is supposed to work, but IME it does not and why does that happen? I am not sure but I guess possibly due to multi-threading of instruction execution. So instruction B moves on to another thread while C to another thread and if burst time of B is significantly greater than C then you may have a situation where C gets executed before B. Its just a guess and may not be true. But the fact is it happens and as a developer you learn to live with such things! :)